# Error while starting Activity from onLongclickListener

Tags: android

i am starting my activity from onlongclicklistener of Imageview but when i pressed the imageview long application stop working

here is my code

```
    img1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v1) {
            if(vibration){
            v.vibrate(300);
            }
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,settings.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        return false;
        }
```

here is my log

[image: Log]

please help

Comment: please show your onCreate() code..

Answer (score 1):

If you are consuming (doing something with) the long click, you need to return **`true`** from your `onLongClick()` method and not `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `finish();` method after calling intent. and change your code to like this

```
img1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View v1) {
        if(vibration){
        v.vibrate(300);
        }
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,settings.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: thanx for answer but unfortunately this code is working android 2.2 but not on android 4.1 :(